# ESPResSo Molecular Dynamic Simulation shows no graphical output in WSL in Win 10

Tags: python, simulation, windows-subsystem-for-linux, physics

I am a scientist who wants to use [ESPResSo MD](https://espressomd.github.io/)
(Extensible Simulation Package for Research on Soft Matter Systems)
for molecular dynamic simulations on my Windows 10 system.
There is a [manual](https://espressomd.github.io/doc/installation.html#installing-requirements-on-windows-via-wsl) for doing this inside of a (Windows-Sub-Linux system) WSL.

When I try to start a sample Script within the build folder with `./pypresso ../samples/billard.py`
It starts the script and opens the visualizer window but it just stays black and nothing happens. There is not even an error message, but this happens with every sample from the sample folder.

What I have done so far is to execute each line from the [Requirements section](https://espressomd.github.io/doc/installation.html#requirements) in WSL and made sure that my WSL is able to output graphics by starting Linux GIMP with it.

What should I do to get graphical output ?
And is there a comfortable way to just use VS Code Jupyter Notebook under Windows for coding my simulations?